# recursive call in nested xml fails

Tags: xslt-2.0

I want to recursively call on element vrijeInhoudGroep, but the node test in the choose clause is not performed. Instead, the second test on element vrijeInhoudElement is successful. Everything I have applied does not work. Can anyone give me a backing?

My xml input:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://services" xmlns:v11="http://services11" xmlns:v12="http://services12">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <v1:creeerDocumentRequest>
            <v11:documentInhoud>
                <v12:vrijeInhoudGroep type="FirstGroep">
                    <v12:vrijInhoudGroep type="GenesteGroep_1">
                        <v12:vrijeInhoudElement>
                            <v12:label>Label1</v12:label>
                            <v12:waarde>waard1</v12:waarde>
                            <v12:datatype>tekst1</v12:datatype>
                        </v12:vrijeInhoudElement>
                        <v12:vrijeInhoudElement>
                            <v12:label>Label2</v12:label>
                            <v12:waarde>waard2</v12:waarde>
                            <v12:datatype>tekst2</v12:datatype>
                        </v12:vrijeInhoudElement>
                        </v12:vrijInhoudGroep>
                    <v12:vrijInhoudGroep type="GenesteGroep_2">
                        <v12:vrijeInhoudElement>
                            <v12:label>Label3</v12:label>
                            <v12:waarde>waard3</v12:waarde>
                            <v12:datatype>tekst3</v12:datatype>
                        </v12:vrijeInhoudElement>
                    </v12:vrijInhoudGroep>
                    <v12:vrijeInhoudElement>
                        <v12:label>Label4</v12:label>
                        <v12:waarde>waard4</v12:waarde>
                        <v12:datatype>tekst4</v12:datatype>
                    </v12:vrijeInhoudElement>
                    <v12:vrijeInhoudElement>
                        <v12:label>Label5</v12:label>
                        <v12:waarde>waard5</v12:waarde>
                        <v12:datatype>tekst5</v12:datatype>
                    </v12:vrijeInhoudElement>                   
                </v12:vrijeInhoudGroep>
            </v11:documentInhoud>
        </v1:creeerDocumentRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My xml output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<vrijeInhoudGroep type="documentInhoud">  
  <vrijeInhoudGroep>v12:vrijeInhoudGroep</vrijeInhoudGroep>  
  <ELLEMENT/>  
  <mywrapper>  
    <v12:label xmlns:soapenv="http://s...">Label4</v12:label>
    <v12:waarde xmlns:soapenv="http://s..." >waard4</v12:waarde>
    <v12:datatype xmlns:soapenv="http://s..." >tekst4</v12:datatype>  
  </mywrapper>  
  <mywrapper>  
    <v12:label xmlns:soapenv="http://s...." >Label5</v12:label>  
    <v12:waarde xmlns:soapenv="http://s..." >waard5</v12:waarde>  
    <v12:datatype xmlns:soapenv="http://s...">tekst5</v12:datatype>  
  </mywrapper>  
</vrijeInhoudGroep>
```

My xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:v11="http://services11" xmlns:v12="http://services12" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:v1="http://services" 
 version="2.0" 
 exclude-result-prefixes="v11 v12 v1 xsi xs">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//v1:creeerDocumentRequest"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="v1:creeerDocumentRequest">
        <vrijeInhoudGroep type="documentInhoud">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="v11:documentInhoud"/>
        </vrijeInhoudGroep>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="v11:documentInhoud">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="v12:vrijeInhoudGroep"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="v12:vrijeInhoudGroep[@type]">
        <vrijeInhoudGroep>
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        </vrijeInhoudGroep>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="v12:vrijeInhoudGroep">
                <!-- HERE I TRY A RECURSIVE CALL, BUT THIS TEST DOES'T WORK -->
                <xsl:apply-templates select="v12:vrijeInhoudGroep"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="v12:vrijeInhoudElement">
                <!-- INSTEAD IT COMES HERE TO PROCES THE vrijeInhoudElement -->
                <ELLEMENT/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="v12:vrijeInhoudElement"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise><NOPE/></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>       

        </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="v12:vrijeInhoudElement">
    <mywrapper>
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
    </mywrapper>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Target xml should be something like this:

```
<...>
        <vrijeInhoudGroep type="EerstGroep">
            <vrijeInhoudGroep type="GenesteGroep_1">
                <vrijeInhoudElement naam="Label1 format="tekst1">waard1</vrijeInhoudElement>
            </vrijeInhoudGroep>
            <vrijeInhoudGroep type="GenesteGroep_2">
                <vrijeInhoudElement naam="Label2 format="tekst2">waard2</vrijeInhoudElement>
                <vrijeInhoudElement naam="Label3 format="tekst3">waard3</vrijeInhoudElement>
                </vrijeInhoudGroep>
            <vrijeInhoudElement naam="Label3 format="tekst3">waard3</vrijeInhoudElement>
            <vrijeInhoudElement naam="Label4 format="tekst4">waard4</vrijeInhoudElement>
        </vrijeInhoudGroep>
</...>
```

What should I do to make this recursive call work properly?

Comment: I've found it: there was a typo in second element vrijInhoudGroep->that should be vrijeInhoudGroep.  Thanx anyway ;-)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You're more likely to get good responses to questions here if you reduce your problem a little more in size.  Strive for the smallest possible example that exhibits your problem.  (Of course, sometimes then your error  becomes obvious to you without actually asking the question. That's just a risk you have to take.)  There is good advice on asking effective questions in the [SO help files](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and in Eric Raymond and Rick Moen's essay [How to ask questions the smart way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).